# Map original data from the dataset to new data using Datavec library and store it in Spark RDDs

Tags: java, data-science, deeplearning4j, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that contains a latitude and longitude written like *20.55E* and *30.11N*. I want to replace these direction strings with an appropriate **-** where required. So basically, I'll map based on the condition and change the value.
Currently, I have a [`Schema`](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/datavec/api/transform/schema/Schema.Builder.html) and I'm trying to sort out the [`TransformProcess`](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/index.html?org/datavec/api/transform/TransformProcess.Builder.html)

My `Schema` is like this:

```
new Schema.Builder()
                .addColumnTime("dt", DateTimeZone.UTC)
                .addColumnsDouble("AverageTemperature" , "AverageTemperatureUncertainty")
                .addColumnsInteger("City" , "Country")
                .addColumnsFloat("Latitude" , "Longitude")
                .build();
```

And I'm stuck with my `TransformProcess` like this:

```
new TransformProcess.Builder(schema)
                .filter(new FilterInvalidValues("AverageTemperature" , "AverageTemperatureUncertainty"))
                .stringToTimeTransform("dt","yyyy-MM-dd", DateTimeZone.UTC)
                . // map currentLatitude -> remove direction string and put sign
```

I am trying to follow [this code](https://github.com/SkymindIO/screencasts/blob/master/datavec_spark_transform/StormReportsRecordReader.java) from a tutorial and after the `TransformProcess`, I'll do the `Spark` stuff and save the data.

My question is:
**How can I perform the mapping?**
From the API docs of `TansformProcess`, I cannot make sense of anything that will help me solve my problem.
I am using the **Datavec** library in **Deeplearning4J**

Comment: So, you want to replace latitude and longitude with `-`?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart If have S and W in for the latitude and longitude respectively, then I want to replace them with a `-`.

Comment: So 30W becomes -30? Or am I not understanding

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Yep, that's correct. And for 50S it becomes -50.

Comment: could you create a function with a regex or indexOf  that returns a 1 or -1 value based on the letter found in the string and then just use parseFloat on the string and multiple it by the returned value from the function?

Comment: @dprogramz I cannot access the value directly at this stage. The library does this underneath. To be honest, the actual data hasn't been read at this point, this is simply some sort of configuration definition that will be passed to some kind of `Spark` class which will do the actual reading and do the stuff.

Comment: ahh, I see. I don't have a lot of Java experience, so this might be totally wrong. But, the hacky way I might try would be to create an intermediary schema for incoming data, convert it to what you need on the save, and then have a separate schema for the saved data that you actually use for things.

Comment: @dprogramz If I have to visualize this, then I would require a map function in either the `Schema` or the `TransformProcess`(which is usually the transformations specifier for the schema) which does the mapping. Either way, there is a requirement of a map, even if I have to hack it via an intermediate schema(I'm thinking of this like a "temp" variable).

Comment: hopefully someone more seasoned than me can come up with a more elegant way, but the temp variable method would probably be my solution as well.